# Access database member of PoolConfig of mysql Pool ojbect

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to get a database from a pool object and assign a different database name to it.

I have been using this function to get a pool. But this function returns a new pool with different config every time.

```
function getPool(database_name){
    if(database_name)
        config.database = database_name;
    var pool = require('mysql').createPool(config);
    console.log(pool);
    return pool;
}
```

I want something like this. so that it returns the same pool with a different configuration.

```
var pool = require('mysql').createPool(config);

function getPool(database_name){
    if(database_name)
        pool.config.PoolConfig.database = database_name;
    console.log(pool);
    return pool;
}
```

In printing out the pool object and try to access the database parameter of the object to modify it. but it didn't work out. How can I access the database element of this object?
Here is the object

```
Pool {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  config:
   PoolConfig {
     acquireTimeout: 10000,
     connectionConfig:
      ConnectionConfig {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        localAddress: undefined,
        socketPath: undefined,
        user: 'root',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'mydatabasename',
        connectTimeout: 10000,
        insecureAuth: false,
        supportBigNumbers: false,
        bigNumberStrings: false,
        dateStrings: false,
        debug: undefined,
        trace: true,
        stringifyObjects: false,
        timezone: 'local',
        flags: '',
        queryFormat: undefined,
        pool: [Circular],
        ssl: false,
        multipleStatements: false,
        typeCast: true,
        maxPacketSize: 0,
        charsetNumber: 33,
        clientFlags: 455631 },
     waitForConnections: true,
     connectionLimit: 10,
     queueLimit: 0,
     database: 'eventx' },
  _acquiringConnections: [],
  _allConnections: [],
  _freeConnections: [],
  _connectionQueue: [],
  _closed: false }
pool connection : [object Object]
```

Comment: You cant change the database name after you established a connection. But what you could do is to connect to the database sever and omit the database name and add them before your tablename in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file pool.js with following code.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
var dbConfigMySql = {
 host: "127.0.0.1",
 user: "user",
 password: "password",
 port: "3306",
 connectionLimit: 15,
 queueLimit: 30,
 acquireTimeout: 1000000
}

const pool = mysql.createPool(dbconifg);

function getPool(database_name){
    pool.config.connectionConfig.multipleStatements = false;
    if(database_name){
        pool.config.connectionConfig.database = database_name;
        return pool;
    }
    else{
        delete pool.config.connectionConfig.database;
        return pool;
    }
}
exports.pool = getPool;
```

Now you can import this file anywhere and use same pool with different database name for example

```
const pool = require("../pool").pool;
pool("yourdatabase").getconnection((error,connection()=>{
    connection.query(....)
})
```